# Is it possible to subclass the financial timeseries class?

Tags: matlab

I have tried subclassing the `fints` class, but it returns the following error:

> The specified superclass 'fints' contains a parse error or cannot be
>   found on MATLAB's search path, possibly shadowed by another file with
>   the same name.

Comment: Post your code for your subclass?

Comment: It's just a declaration:
`classdef myclass < fints end` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `fints` is an old MATLAB "OOPS"-style class, which is not compatible with subclassing via the newer `classdef` MATLAB class system. See http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/compatibility-with-previous-versions-.html for more.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I hope MathWorks fix this.